# Listar todos los actores con el total número de películas en las que aparece y el listado de los títulos de cada película

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, modelorelacional

Yo soy nuevo en MySQL y necesito ayuda por favor.
Todos hemos sido nuevos y novatos alguna vez.

Yo quiero listar todos los actores con el total número de películas en las que aparece y el listado de los títulos de cada película.

Esta es mi consulta:

```
SELECT actor.name, COUNT(film.id) AS films, film.title
    FROM actor
    LEFT JOIN film 
    ON actor.id=film.idActor
```

Este es mi resultado obtenido: (solo obtengo 1 registro de un actor que aparece en las 10 películas que tengo en mi base de datos)

Name        Films  Title

Vin Diesel    10    Fast And Furious

Yo quiero obtener todos los actores con el número total de películas que han hecho y con sus títulos.

Comment: ¿Cómo se relaciona en la base de datos cada actor con sus películas? En algún sitio debes tener una correspondencia entre el id de película y los ids de los actores que salen en ellas, esa es la clave para relacionar la tabla film con la tabla actor.

Comment: Hola @Carmen
Gracias por tu respuesta.
Sí, en la clase tabla film tengo el id del actor y en la actor tengo el id del film.
Por eso lo relaciono con el inner join.
Por favor, ¿me puedes ayudar?
Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes probar con:

- `GROUP_CONCAT` :Esto ayudará a que el listado completo de películas correspondientes a cada actor aparezca en una sola celda
- Agrupamos por el nombre del actor ya que al tener una función de agregación deberás hacer lo que menciono por las columnas restantes
- Dado el contexto de tu ejercicio debes hacer uso de `INNER JOIN/JOIN` para que solo devuelva a los actores cuyo id aparece como llave foránea en al menos una película en la otra tabla ignorando a aquellos actores que no han participado en alguna película

Puede quedar así:

```
SELECT actor.name, 
        COUNT(film.id) AS films, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(film.title) Listado
FROM actor
JOIN film ON actor.id=film.idActor
GROUP BY actor.name;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda.
Un saludo.

Answer (score 3):

Tal y como comentas que está estructurada la base de datos, el resultado sería listar todas las películas ordenadas por actor y con una subquery obtener el número total de películas en las que aparece.

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE actor (
  id INT,
  id_film INT,
  name VARCHAR(100)
);
INSERT INTO actor (id, id_film, name) VALUES (1, 1, "Pepito Pérez");
INSERT INTO actor (id, id_film, name) VALUES (2, 2, "Juan García");
INSERT INTO actor (id, id_film, name) VALUES (3, 1, "María Gómez");
INSERT INTO actor (id, id_film, name) VALUES (3, 3, "María Gómez");
INSERT INTO actor (id, id_film, name) VALUES (1, 4, "Pepito Pérez");

CREATE TABLE film (
  id INT,
  title VARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT INTO film (id, title) VALUES (1, "Película 1");
INSERT INTO film (id, title) VALUES (2, "Película 2");
INSERT INTO film (id, title) VALUES (3, "Película 3");
INSERT INTO film (id, title) VALUES (4, "Película 4");
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, f.title,
(
  SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM actor a2
  WHERE a2.id=a.id
) AS total
FROM actor a
INNER JOIN film f ON a.id_film=f.id
ORDER BY a.id
;

| id  | name         | title      | total |
| --- | ------------ | ---------- | ----- |
| 1   | Pepito Pérez | Película 1 | 2     |
| 1   | Pepito Pérez | Película 4 | 2     |
| 2   | Juan García  | Película 2 | 1     |
| 3   | María Gómez  | Película 1 | 2     |
| 3   | María Gómez  | Película 3 | 2     |
```

---

Lo que sucede con este tipo de base de datos es que tiene un problema de diseño, porque cuando varios actores participan en una película hay que repetir la información del actor y/o película, lo más lógico sería tener una tabla para actores, otra para películas y otra para relacionar ambas.

Ejemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE actor (
  id INT,
  name VARCHAR(100)
);
INSERT INTO actor (id, name) VALUES (1, "Pepito Pérez");
INSERT INTO actor (id, name) VALUES (2, "Juan García");
INSERT INTO actor (id, name) VALUES (3, "María Gómez");

CREATE TABLE film (
  id INT,
  title VARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT INTO film (id, title) VALUES (1, "Película 1");
INSERT INTO film (id, title) VALUES (2, "Película 2");
INSERT INTO film (id, title) VALUES (3, "Película 3");
INSERT INTO film (id, title) VALUES (4, "Película 4");

CREATE TABLE actor_film (
  id_film INT,
  id_actor INT
);

INSERT INTO actor_film VALUES (1,1);
INSERT INTO actor_film VALUES (1,2);
INSERT INTO actor_film VALUES (1,3);
INSERT INTO actor_film VALUES (1,4);
INSERT INTO actor_film VALUES (2,1);
INSERT INTO actor_film VALUES (2,3);
INSERT INTO actor_film VALUES (3,2);
INSERT INTO actor_film VALUES (4,1);
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

Espero que esto te sirva.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda.
Un saludo.